# get only newest object from a model - laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.3

I have two models: `Supplier` and `Quotation`. I can use a `foreach` to list all quotations of a supplier:

```
// in my `Supplier` model:
public function quotations()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotation', 'supplier_id');
}
```

And now I want to print only the most recent quotation. The best I can figure out is this function in model:

```
public function newestQuotation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotation', 'supplier_id')->orderBy('offered_at','desc')->limit(1);
}
```

and this `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach($o->newestQuotation as $q)
     @include('displaymodules.module_quotations_mini', array('bg_color' => 'bg-danger'))
@endforeach
```

### TO DO:

The above code does the job... but how it can be done properly? I am thinking of doing a helper, but doing the function in my models seems more like a good practice.

Thank you

## Edited:

maybe I wasn't clear enough... I don't want to use foreach to access the object. 
What I want is a snippet like this:

`@include('displaymodules.module_quotations_mini', array( 'q' => $o->latestQuotations))`

I get such an object when the query has the `->first()`, but not when it has '->get()`.
when I do

$latestQuotation = App\Models\Quotation:where('supplier_id', 3)->orderBy('offered_at, 'desc')->first();

### to get what I want without foreach I use this this temporary solution

```
<?php 
$latestQuotation = App\Models\Quotation::where('supplier_id', $o->id)->orderBy('offered_at', 'desc')->first(); 

?>
@if(isset($latestQuotation))
    @include('displaymodules.module_quotations_mini', array('bg_color' => 'csch_subtle_3', 'q' => $latestQuotation))
@endif
```

### Attempts to implement Krishan Koenig's answer

#### attempt #1

```
<?php $latestQuotations = $o->latestQuotations(); ?>

{{print_r($latestQuotations)}}
```

Result: domain.dev is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

#### attempt #2

```
{{$o->latestQuotations()->offered_at}}
```

or

```
{{$o->latestQuotations->offered_at}}
```

Result: 
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$offered_at (View:\resources\views\leads\_show_bestoffers.blade.php) (View: \resources\views\leads\_show_bestoffers.blade.php)`

#### attempt #3 - my desired solution

@include('displaymodules.module_quotations_mini', array('bg_color' => 'csch_subtle_5', 'q' => $o->latestQuotations))

Result: 
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$offered_at (View:\resources\views\leads\_show_bestoffers.blade.php) (View: \resources\views\leads\_show_bestoffers.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new scope in related model, call it like latest:

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('offered_at','desc')->limit(1);
}
```

and then in your relationship:

```
public function newestQuotation()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotation', 'supplier_id')->latest();
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it work. Take a look a my edits to the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new relatiotion in `Supplier` Model as:

```
public function newestQuotation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Quotation', 'supplier_id')->orderBy('offered_at', 'desc');
}
```

Then you can query it as:

```
$supplieres = Supplier::with('newestQuotation')->take(20)->get();

@foreach ($supplieres as $supplier)
  {{ $supplier->newestQuotation->title }} // just an example
@endforeach
```

**Update**

Try your query as:

```
$supplier = Supplier::where('id', $id)->first();

$latestQuotation = $supplier->newestQuotation;
```

Comment: You just have re-created my temporary solution with foreach. Does it mean that it's impossible to get the object without the need to iterate. There is only one object in the collection! Please take a look at my edits

Comment: `foreach` is just for demo purpose. Try the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Quotation.php model

```
class Quotation extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        function withSupplier() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotation', 'id', 'supplier_id')->orderBy('offered_at','desc');
    }

    public function newestQuotation($supplier_id){
         News::with('withSupplier')->where('supplier_id', $supplier_id)->get();
    }
}
```

in contriller:

```
public function pageQuotations(Quotation $quotation)
    {
        $quotations = $quotation->newestQuotation(1); //id Supplier
        return view('displaymodules.quotations', $quotations);
    }
```

in quotations.blade.php (example)

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach ($quotations as $quotation)
<tr>
<th>{{ $quotation->title }}</th>
<td>{{ $quotation->withSupplier()->title }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It won't work. I don't want to use `foreach`. Scopes seem to be the right way to get what I want. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope and use your existing relationship!

```
public function quotations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotation', 'supplier_id');
}


public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('offered_at','desc')->limit(1);
}

public function latestQuotations()
{
    return $this->quotations()->latest();
}
```

And in your Controller you query them with

```
//...
$latestQuotations = $supplier->latestQuotations();
```

**Edited Version**:

```
// supplier model
public function quotations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Quotation::class);
}

public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('offered_at','desc');
}

public function latestQuotations()
{
    return $this->quotations()->latest()->get();
}

// web route
Route::get('/', function () {
    $latestQuotations = App\Supplier::first()->latestQuotations();
    return view('welcome', compact('latestQuotations'));
});

// welcome view
{{ $latestQuotations }}
```

...worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot make it work. Please take a look at my attempts in edits I just made at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is

`$entity = $collection->first();`

Then, whateverthe count of the collection, the result is a single object.
This allows to use terms such as `$entity->id` or `$entity->name`.